# Double driver export script

Tags: windows, batch-file, wmic, sccm

I'm terrible at scripting, so I would like some help with a script which does the following:

a wmic query:

> wmic computersystem get model
>   Latitude E7450

creates a folder in the root using the query output without spaces:

> Latitude_E7450

Then run double driver to backup all the drivers and storing them in the newly created folder:

```
ddc b /source:"c:\Windows" /target:"c:\Latitude_E7450"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get name for the target folder from the WMI Model using powershell, assuming WMI returns this (some OEM units don't),

```
$dirName = (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem).Model
```

Then you can call Double Driver,

```
& ddc.exe b /source:"C:\Windows" /target:"C:\$dirName"
```

For a pure powershell solution, see for example this post from Mikael Nyström, "[PowerShell is King – Export drivers from Windows](https://deploymentbunny.com/2016/02/26/powershell-is-king-export-drivers-from-windows/)"

```
Export-WindowsDriver -Destination "C:\Drivers\$((Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem).Model)" -Online
```

This requires Windows 6.3 at least (8.1 or 2012 R2), so use Double Driver for Win 7, if you can still find it. For even more bells and whistles, see "[Building Configuration Manager Driver Packages for Windows 7 with PowerShell and Double Driver](https://systemcentersupport.org/2016/04/19/building-configuration-manager-driver-packages-for-windows-7-with-powershell-and-double-driver)".